# Loading the jQuery function with parent on iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering why this is not possible...

I have a file index.php with an iframe

```
index.php
->iframe.php
```

The index.php file has executed the **jquery.js**, and on the iframe I write this

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = parent.jQuery;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#test").html('Hello World');
});
```

I know it is maybe not very useful, but I want to know if is possible something like this.

Comment: window.top.jQuery might work... might.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your jquery code, replace your following line:

```
$("div#test").('Hello World');
```

for this one:

```
$("div#test").html('Hello World');
```

Comment: In my file is well written, I failed here, that is not the reason

Answer (score 1):

try this(i dont have a webserver right now so not sure if any of those can work):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
      //try this 
      //object = parent.$(parent.document)
      //object.find('body').append('<p>ello</p>')

      //or this
      //$('body',parent.document).append('<p>ello</p>')
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Yep, as I said I know it isn't very useful the solution of my question, it is curiosity, I know I can acces iframe elements from parent with .contents()

Answer (score 0):

Okay, My code is working fine, I can call the jQuery function, but they functions called on iframe are executed on parent DOM!